# Setting dynamic parameter of height on iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my pages url to add the params of the height of the page so I can set it up as a dynamic height on the page that loads in the iframe.

The iframe pages code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var h = $("#tr").height();
var pathname = $(location).attr('href');
pathname = $(this) + "&height=" + h;
});
```

The page that loads in the iframe.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// parse params in iframe url

var qs = (function(a) {
if (a == "") return {};
var b = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
{
    var p=a[i].split('=');
    if (p.length != 2) continue;
    b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
    return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));

// get height param
var myheight = qs["height"]
// apply css height of the iframe parent
$("#frame").css("height", myheight)
});
```

The problem is that the iframe page so far isn't adding "page.html&height=800" on page load and I'm trying to figure out how to set it to do that possible without refreshing.

Comment: If you're trying to append parameters to the URL you should use the correct syntax: `page.html?height=800` ( [Query String Doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) ). In this case @Diodeus's answer provides a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use a URL hash, not a parameter.

```
 "page.html#height=800"
```

`document.location.hash` holds "height=800" which you can parse (or set).

You can change the hash value without affecting page load.